# White line when emebding pdf in html

Tags: html, css, pdf, embed

I am creating an web-application using node-webkit, which bases on googles chrome browser. 
When embedding a pdf file on a site, using the embed tag, ich get a white line on the top of the embeded part (picture attached). My first thought was, that it is a kind of border, but setting border = 0 dont resolves the problem.
My suggestion is, that this white line is part of the background of the embed part and adobes pdf plugin doesnt covers the whole embed area. 
[image]

### Edit

If my suggestion is true, then it would already help me if i could switch the background of the embed area to an other color. But setting background-color doesnt works too.

Comment: Is there a whitespace in front of the embed-tag?

Comment: No there's not a whitespace.

Comment: Please add the following css to the embed-tag: `<embed style="border: solid 1px red;" ...` and upload the screenshot, so that we can see, if the space is within the embed or without. It might also help if you can post (parts of) the html source code.

Answer (score 0):

Margin and padding has to be set to 0 on the html/body.

Comment: This has no effect. Line is still there.

Answer (score 0):

If you add:

```
body { 
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

That should sort your problem out.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `<iframe></iframe>` tag. set the source of your file in `src` atribute. you can set the height or width of iframe tag as you set your embed tag. 
example : `<iframe src="http://example.example/file.pdf" width="500" height="400"></iframe>`
or you can set the application to open the file you attached to your website

might it help! :D

Comment: what's the pdf plugin do you use? may be that's a default of your plugin.